# Div with overlay and button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need of add overlay opacity 0.5 up on

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

             </div>
```

div has the css

```
 .panel.panel-default {
    border-top-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}
.panel {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 2px solid #E5E5E5;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.panel-default {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    /* border-radius: 4px; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
html * {
    outline: none !important;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}
```

Now I would like the div with opacity above 0.5, and the center of this opaque div I enter 4 buttons at the center vertically and horizontally

so I have to insert a new div to the opacity and another div for 4 buttons central,

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div style="overlay"><div style="bottons">1</div><div style="bottons">2</div><div style="bottons">3</div><div style="bottons">4</div></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qu62mvkk/10/

http://jsfiddle.net/qu62mvkk/13/

Comment: Please, provide a fiddle

Comment: Also, provide an actual _question_. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Do not use opacity because all children elements will inherit this, use background-color RGBA instead. eg:

background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5),

this will make only your selected div with opacity.

Comment: That's right, now, to center your buttons, you can use translate, eg: position:absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; translate(-50%, -50%)

Comment: Yes, it is a transform attribute, eg: transform: translate(-50%,-50%), see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: @CredoMutwa Mask as right answer to help future people with the same doubt